# Product of two Beta distributed random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, beta-function

I have two Beta distributed random variables :

$X_1=B(\alpha_1, \beta_1)$

$X_2=B(\alpha_2, \beta_2)$

What can we say about $Y=X_1.X_2$? Is this also a Beta distributed random variable?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889025/product-of-two-beta-distributions).

Comment: A general solution is derived at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201321/if-x-1-x-2-are-independent-beta-then-showing-sqrtx-1x-2-is-beta/2441409

Comment: Do not forget to state that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent!

Answer (score 4):

There are several paper for this problem. See for example:

- [On the Distribution of the Product of Independent Beta Random Variables
  – Applications](http://www.dm.fct.unl.pt/sites/www.dm.fct.unl.pt/files/preprints/2012/7_12.pdf)
- [Products of Beta distributed random variables](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6671v1.pdf)
- [BETA PRODUCTS WITH COMPLEX PARAMETERS](http://fbe.unimelb.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0009/806256/164.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the following paper http://www.dm.fct.unl.pt/sites/www.dm.fct.unl.pt/files/preprints/2012/7_12.pdf which tackles your problem