# Product of two Beta Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X \sim Beta(a, b)$ and $Y \sim Beta(c, d)$, independently, such that $a = c + d$, find the distribution of
$XY$

How to tackle this problem?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Try adding the general forms for $X,Y$ together.

Comment: I tried adding the Beta together since are independent but can't simply further

Comment: @Florent Adding what? Use a change of variables like $(x,y)\to (xy,x)$.

Comment: Sorry I meant multiplying together. I'm using w=xy then trying to simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is through moment generating functions and by considering the log-transformed variables.

Let $$X' = -\log X, \quad Y' = -\log Y.$$ Then 
$$\begin{align*}
M_{X'}(t) &= \operatorname{E}[e^{tX'}] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[e^{-t \log X}] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X^{-t}] \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{\Gamma(c+d+b)}{\Gamma(c+d)\Gamma(b)} x^{-t} x^{c+d-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(c+d+b)}{\Gamma(c+d)} \frac{\Gamma(c+d-t)}{\Gamma(c+d+b-t)} \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{\Gamma(c+d+b-t)}{\Gamma(c+d-t) \Gamma(b)} x^{c+d-t-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(c+d+b)\Gamma(c+d-t)}{\Gamma(c+d)\Gamma(c+d+b-t)}, \quad t < c+d.
\end{align*}$$
Similarly, $$M_Y'(t) = \frac{\Gamma(c+d)\Gamma(c-t)}{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c+d-t)}.$$
Therefore, if $W = XY$ and $W' = -\log W = X' + Y'$, we have $$M_{W'}(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{-t(X' + Y')}] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{E}[e^{-tX'}]\operatorname{E}[e^{-tY'}] = M_{X'}(t)M_{Y'}(t) = \frac{\Gamma(c+d+b)\Gamma(c-t)}{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c+d+b-t)}.$$  This is the MGF for a negative log-transformed beta distribution with parameters $\alpha = c$, $\beta = d+b$.

---

*Mathematica* single-input computation:

```
FullSimplify[PDF[TransformedDistribution[x y, {Distributed[x,
    BetaDistribution[c + d, b], Distributed[y, BetaDistribution[c, d]}], w] 
    - PDF[BetaDistribution[c, b + d], w], 0 < w < 1]
```

This returns $0$.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. The first way I can't use confluent hyper-geometric function because we did only chapter 1-3 in inference class.

Comment: I can't find the  full simplification of Beta distribution for W from W'

Comment: @Florent Everything you need to write a full solution is contained in my answer, but you have to do some additional thinking to understand why my answer works.  When I wrote down the MGF for $Y'$, that formula tells you the MGF for **any** negative log-transformed beta distribution in terms of the parameters.  Therefore, for a suitable choice of parameters for $W'$, you can identify that $W'$ is also negative log-transformed beta.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but @heropup do you know of a good reference for using the probability functions in Mathematica? The built-in help wasn't very useful.

Comment: Also, does your answer agree with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201321/if-x-1-x-2-are-independent-beta-then-showing-sqrtx-1x-2-is-beta/2441409 ? The results seem to be different.

Comment: @Math1000 I disagree with the reason for closure because the transformation is different, and your case is more general, having three free parameters rather than two.  However, I see no reason to reopen the question and I regard it as having been answered.

Comment: @Math1000 This is definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: Okay, I have voted to reopen. @StubbornAtom

Comment: @Math1000 Looks like OP himself marked it it as a duplicate. Not voting to reopen this unless he adds some personal input on the problem.