# Deriving Marginal Distribution from Two Independent Beta Distributions

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, density-function, marginal-distribution

I have two *independent* random variables:

1. $X$ is Beta($a, b$), $x \in [0, 1]$
2. $Y$ is Beta($a+b, \gamma$), $y \in [0, 1]$

$$f(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)} x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\frac{\Gamma(a+b+\gamma)}{\Gamma(a+b)\Gamma(\gamma)}y^{a+b-1} (1-y)^{\gamma-1}$$

I want to perform the transformations for $U = XY$, $V=Y$.
$$U=XY \rightarrow U=XY \rightarrow X=U/V, \qquad u \in [0,1]$$
$$V=Y \rightarrow Y=V, \qquad v\in[0,1]$$

$$\det{J}= \frac{1}{v}*1-0=\frac{1}{v}$$
So I have,

$$f(u, v) = \frac{\Gamma(a+b+\gamma)}{\Gamma(a+b)\Gamma(\gamma)} (u/v)^{a-1}(1-(u/v))^{b-1}v^{a+b-1} (1-v)^{\gamma-1} * \frac{1}{v}, \qquad 0 \le u \le v \le 1$$

I want to find the marginal distribution of $u$.

$$f_{U}(u) = \frac{\Gamma(a+b+\gamma)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(\gamma)} u^{a-1} \int^1_{u} (1-(u/v))^{b-1}v^{a+b-1} (1-v)^{\gamma-1} \frac{1}{v} dv$$

**QUESTION:** However, I am unsure how to go about this integral. How can I proceed *with this integration* find the marginal distribution for $U$?

Comment: Your Point 2:  If  $Y \sim \text{Beta}(a+b, \gamma)$, then $f(y)$ will have in the denominator $\Gamma(a+b)\Gamma(\gamma)$ ... not   $\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(\gamma)$

Comment: @wolfies : this is a typo because going on the OP amended this error

Comment: Previously asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3590757/321264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X\sim \text{Beta}(a,b)$ and $Y\sim \text{Beta}(c,d)$ are independently distributed with $c=a+b$.

Then $(X,Y)$ has density $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)\propto x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}y^{c-1}(1-y)^{d-1}\mathbf1_{0<x,y<1}\,,$$ where  $a,b,c,d>0$.

Transforming $(X,Y)\mapsto (U,V)=(XY,Y)$, density of $(U,V)$ is

\begin{align}
f_{U,V}(u,v)&=f_{X,Y}\left(\frac{u}{v},v\right)\cdot\frac1v
\\&\propto u^{a-1}(v-u)^{b-1}(1-v)^{d-1}\mathbf1_{0<u<v<1}
\end{align}

Pdf of $U$ is therefore

$$f_U(u)\propto u^{a-1}\int_u^1 (v-u)^{b-1}(1-v)^{d-1}\,dv\,\mathbf1_{0<u<1}$$

Now you can turn this integral into a Beta function if you change variables $v\mapsto t$ such that $t=0$ when $v=u$ and $t=1$ when $v=1$. This yields the relation $v-u=t(1-u)$.

On simplification you have another Beta distribution:

$$f_U(u)\propto u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b+d-1}\,\mathbf1_{0<u<1}$$

I have ignored the normalizing constants here since these are all guaranteed to be valid densities. You can of course verify that you end up with the correct constant.

Comment: This variable's change is really interesting.... (+1). I had some problem to solve that integral thus I bypassed it using the Dirichlet

Comment: I don't see the connection to Dirichlet.

Answer (score 0):

The joint density results to me

$$f(u,v-u,1-v)=\frac{\Gamma(a+b+\gamma)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(\gamma)}u^{a-1}(v-u)^{b-1}(1-v)^{\gamma-1}$$

This is a [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) with parameters $(a,b,\gamma)$ thus it is immediate to derive the 3 marginal laws:

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
U\sim Beta(a; b  +\gamma)
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
(V-U)\sim Beta(b; a  +\gamma)
\qquad (2) 
}
$$

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid blue]
{
(1-V)\sim Beta(\gamma; a+b)
\qquad (3) 
}
$$

(3) is an obvious result, knowing that $V\sim Beta(a+b;\gamma)$

Comment: '$f(u,v-u,1-v)$' is meaningless, making this argument unclear.

Answer (score 0):

See *Statistical Inference* by *Casella & Berger* Example 4.3.3; they do this exact example. You need to do a change of variable $y=(u/v-u)/(1-u)$ (non-obvious substitution), so that $dy=-u[v^2(1-u)]dv$. The main reason for this is to change the bounds of the integral where the lower bound is $0$ and the upper bound is $1$ so you can use the Beta pdf to compute the new integral.

**Answer**:

> If $X\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ and $Y\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha+\beta,\gamma)$ are independent, then $U=XY$ and $V=X$ yields $U\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta+\gamma)$.